# Python gspread range in format 'A2:A', A1 notation

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, spreadsheet, gspread

In gspread, if I do the following

```
wks.range('D2:D13')
```

I get no errors.

However, if I want to get all rows in the 'D' column from row 2, using A1 notation I get an error:

```
wks.range('D2:D')
```

Error:

```
raise IncorrectCellLabel(label)
gspread.exceptions.IncorrectCellLabel: D
```

According to the gspread api reference, [Worksheet.range should be using A1 notation](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Worksheet.range).
What I'm trying to do seems to be correct according to [Google's Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation).

What's going on here? Does gspread not support the format or am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Preface

In investigating this particularly problem, I found it really strange that there isn't a crystal clear **gspread** method to grab a single range in A1 notation from a Google Worksheet, but I believe there is a reason for this.

As noted in the documentation the creator of gspread wants to reduce the API calls made to the Google Sheet API: https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/user-guide.html#getting-all-values-from-a-row-or-a-column.

---

## The Answer

Anyways, there's a sneaky gspread provided method to get a particularly range or range(s) via the **batch_get** method. You should try:

```
wks.batch_get( ('D2:D',) )[0]
```

Better yet, if you wanted to get a couple different ranges all at once (with one API call), you could call:

```
ranges = wks.batch_get( ('D2:D', 'A2:A') )
```

Answer (score 1):

- You want to retrieve the values using the a1Notation of `D2:D` using gspread with python.
- In the current stage, when `wks.range('D2:D')` is run, an error, which is shown in your question, occurs.
- You want to know the reason of this error.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Issue and workaround:

When I confirmed [the source script of `range()`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/models.py#L550), when `range()` is run, it was found that the values are retrieved with `data = self.spreadsheet.values_get(range_label)`. So in this case, `D2:D` can be used.

But [`(last_row, last_column) = a1_to_rowcol(end)`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/models.py#L586) is run, the error occurs. The script of `a1_to_rowcol()` can be seen at [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/utils.py#L135).

When `a1_to_rowcol()` is confirmed, `D2` of `D2:D` returns the value from the regex of [`CELL_ADDR_RE = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z]+)([1-9]\d*)')`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/utils.py#L27). But `D` of `D2:D` doesn't return the value from the regex. By this, `raise IncorrectCellLabel(label)` is run, and then, such error occurs.

#### Workaround:

In order to retrieve the values using the a1Notation of `D2:D`, how about the following workaround? In this workaround, the method of [`values_get(range, params=None)`](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_get) is used. In this case, `D2:D` can be used for retrieving the values from Spreadsheet.

### Sample script:

```
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
spreadsheetId = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sh = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
res = sh.values_get("Sheet1!D2:D")  # Please set the a1Notation.
print(res)  # or print(res['values'])
```

- In this case, the values of cells `D2:D` on the sheet of `Sheet1` are retrieved.
- When the sheet name is not used like `res = sh.values_get("D2:D")`, the values are retrieved from the 1st tab in the Spreadsheet.

### References:

- [values_get](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#gspread.models.Spreadsheet.values_get)
- [gspread on GitHub](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! You got it mostly right. However, I intend to use update_cells() which accepts a list of Cell objects. The range() funcion returns a list of Cells, but as far as I know values_get() sadly does not.

Comment: @Rezic Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for resolving your issue. When your issue was resolved by yourself, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: If I find an answer, I will!